Why I am getting Slow File System detected error in my Next Js 15 project?
I was developing a website in Next Js 15 using pnpm on my old PC running Linux Mint. While starting the development server using pnpm dev, I get this warning:

Slow filesystem detected. If /home/user/Documents/shopify/.next is a
network drive, consider moving it to a local folder. If you have an
antivirus enabled, consider excluding your project directory.

Is it because I am using an HDD instead of an SSD? I am not using a network drive as I am running linux mint directly on my HDD, and I don't have an antivirus software running currently.
I tried running the same codebase on my modern SSD laptop and I don't get the error. So, is it primarily because of my HDD or is there something else going on?

I delete all node_modules in my monorepo and delete .next folder.
Reinstall all packages and run dev script and it work for me.

It doesn't work for me tho... After reinstalling node modules and running pnpm dev, the warning still shows...moreover, next Image also shows blurry images (i guess because next considers my pc to be slow and optimize it too much)
